# Generic $.ajax() call function for resusability

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating a application where I have lot of ajax calls to a remote server and use them extensively. As the code is almost same in all calls, I want to create a new function which I can reuse. I am struck up in defining the parameter structure for the "data" parameter. I will explain below my problem.

Sample of my current ajax call is provided below.

**Current Call Sample:**

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() {
        $.mobile.loading('show');
    },
    complete: function() {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost/test-url/',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {appkey: '1234567', action: 'action1','name':'me'},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/javascript",
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
    async: false,
    error: function() {
        //some operations
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //some operations
    }
});
```

**The re-usable function that I have created:**

```
function newAjax(parm, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            $.mobile.loading('show');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        },
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost/test-url',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {appkey: '1234567', parm: parm},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: "application/javascript",
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
        async: false,
        success: function() {
            successCallback();
        },
        error: function() {
            errorCallback();
        }
    });
}
```

**Question:**

- I will be passing the the parameters for the ajax call via "parm" parameter. I want the data value to be directly added to the parent "data" parameter. And not as a sub-object of data. The appKey remains same across all calls and so I keep it in the actual function.
- I want both the success and error callback functions to be optional. If not provided they should be ignored.

Comment: just a note, `contentType: "application/javascript",` doesn't make sense (you're sending GET params to the server, not javascript...), and `crossDomain: true,` is almost never needed. Also, since you're properly using callbacks, `async: false` isn't needed. Lastly, since you're using jsonp, none of the aforementioned parameters are used anyway.

Comment: You need to look at `extend()`... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? [jQuery.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

Comment: It looks like you're just throwing everything you can think of into the request without understanding what the parameters do.

Comment: The request does a cross-domain call so I added those parameters. It uses jsonp, so I read somewhere to use the contentType.. I am learning all these stuffs.. so excuse me for my errors :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can use the [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend) method to combine two or more objects together.

   ```
   data: jQuery.extend({appkey: '1234567'}, parm),
   ```
2. You can check that you were actually passed functions for `successCallback` and `errorCallback` using `typeof var === 'function'`;

   ```
   success: function () {
       if (typeof successCallback === 'function') {
           successCallback();
       }
   }, 

   error: function () {
       if (typeof errorCallback === 'function') {
           errorCallback();
       }
   }
   ```

   ... although it might be *nicer* if you just returned the Promise created by the AJAX request, and let the caller add their success, error handlers if they wanted;

   ```
   function newAjax(parm) {
      return jQuery.ajax({
          /* as before, but without success and error defined */
      });
   }
   ```

   ... then:

   ```
   newAjax().done(function () {
       // Handle done case
   }).fail(function () {
       // Handle error case.
   });
   ```

   If a caller doesn't want to add an error handler, they just don't call `fail()`;

   ```
   newAjax().done(function () {
       // Handle done case
   });
   ```